# QMYSQL driver not loaded QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt

Estou tentando fazer conexão com o banco de dados com o QtCreator da seguinte maneira:

```
this->db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
this->db.setHostName("localhost");
this->db.setDatabaseName("Pessoa");
this->db.setUserName("root");
this->db.setPassword("");
if(this->db.open();
```

Mas a aplicação retorna:

> QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
>   QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7

Já instalei o `qt-mysql` e no .pro `QT += sql`. O que devo fazer além disso para ter conexão?

Obs.:

Versão do Qt = 5.2.1

SO = GNU/Linux Fedora

Comment: Você verificou se o `qt-mysql` acessível em PATH? Se você instalou enquanto o Qt estava aberto, é necessário reiniciar o Qt (pelo menos no Windows).

Comment: Adicionei o caminho para a variável ambiente, mas mesmo assim continua retornando o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi instalando o pacote

> qt5-qtbase-mysql

e copiando o arquivo

> /usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so

substituindo o arquivo localizado em

> /opt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so.

Answer (score 0):

Certifique-se de que a biblioteca do mysql está em um local acessível ao Qt (`/usr/lib/`, `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` ou algo do tipo).

Como você disse que já instalou o mysql, você deve encontrar a seguinte biblioteca:

`libmysqlclient_r.so` ou `libmysqlclient.so` ou `libmysqlclient_r.so.16`

É essa biblioteca que o Qt necessita para rodar o driver do mysql, como pode ser visto no .pro que compila o driver mysql do Qt, nesse trecho:

```
unix {
    isEmpty(QT_LFLAGS_MYSQL) {
        !contains(LIBS, .*mysqlclient.*):!contains(LIBS, .*mysqld.*) {
            use_libmysqlclient_r:LIBS += -lmysqlclient_r
            else:LIBS += -lmysqlclient
        }
    }
} else {
    !contains(LIBS, .*mysql.*):!contains(LIBS, .*mysqld.*):LIBS += -llibmysql
}
```

---

Se o nome da biblioteca estiver diferente, pode ser que o Qt não esteja encontrando e, por isso, não consegue criar o driver. Se for o caso, você pode tentar criar uma ligação entre a biblioteca que você tem e o nome reconhecível.

Exemplo:

```
ln -s libmysqlclient_r.so libmysqlclient_r.so.16
```

Comment: a versão da lib que eu possuo é a dezoito, localizada em /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18.

Comment: Acho que se você renomar a 18 para só `libmysqlclient_r.so` resolve também.